# Reliability polynomial of Cartesian produt of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, percolation

The all-terminal reliability $R(p)$ of a graph is the probability that the graph remains connected after edges fail independently with probability $p$. Similar the two-terminal reliability $T_{u,v}(p)$ is the probability that the vertices $u$ and $v$ are in the same connected component after edges fail with probability $p$.

Are there any results that link the reliability polynomials of two graphs $G$, $H$ to the reliability polynomials of their Cartesian product $G\square H$?